# Responsive design frameworks

Tags: responsive-design

Hello I'm about to implement  responsive design for a major companies primary website which gets about 14 million unique visitors a month. I'm setting up the basic front end architecture and was wondering on any ideas and techniques that could make life easier. Was looking into backbone for mvvc, Zurb foundation, respond js for ie8, replace js for reducing http calls, GUI minifier...any suggestions that have made everyone's life easier after going down the same path??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I currently have a platform that runs the same UX on chrome, ie8+, ff, opera, safari, ios, and android.

I would say do a lot of testing, and make sure to only use cross browser implementations.

Try not to be too cutting edge, or you will drown yourself trying to spotfix the environments which do not support those features. http://www.caniuse.com is a nice resource.

Avoid using explicit sizing.

Comment: Do u use replace js or anything like tnat

Comment: @ScootaP - I don't use `require.js` (but it seems to be popular, nothing against it). There are two paths to really look at, either having unique experiences per environment or having the same experience for all environments. I took the latter approach and made sure to tailor my scripting and css design to be universal.

Comment: so I'm confused on what u mean by that? Are u talking about responsive design?